# data type used to store discount in sql php

Tags: php, sql

I need to create a table for product management in that table field include like price , image , discount so any one can help me that which datatype is used for all of them.

Comment: Ask yourself: What values will be stored in these columns? Then find a datatype that can store these values

Comment: please post what you have already tried

Comment: On SQL: smallmoney, image, smallmoney

Comment: Price and discount can be `INTEGER` (in pennies/cents or whatever your smallest currency unit is) and the image can be a `VARCHAR` to a relative path on your disk. Don't store binary blobs in the database if you can help it.

Comment: create table product(id int(11) not null auto_increment,
 p_name varchar(50) not null,
 p_sdescription varchar(255) not null,
 p_fdescription varchar(50) not null,
 p_size varchar(50) not null,
 p_price varchar(50) not null,
 P_discount decimal(5,2) not null,
 p_price decimal(5,2) not null,
 p_image image,
 p_sprice decimal(5,2) not null,
 p_date timestamp not null,
 p_status tinyint not null,
 category_id int(11) not null,
 index(category_id));

Comment: ^ Please add that to your question, Akshat, and delete the comment. It is not very readable there. If it gives you an error, please also say what that error is.

Comment: you might also want to indicate the flavor of SQL you are using -- looks like MySQL based on your attempted CREATE statement. Do you plan to store the discount so that it is a whole number percentage (i.e. for a 5% discount you could store 0.05 which would be the discount factor, or you could store 5 as an integer and, in your code, remember to "divide by 100" to make it a "percent".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a simple question as it seems at first look. I suggest you to read first how floats is implemented in different databases and programming languages. It will help you understand why you never shoud use floats to sotre money.

This article [Always use decimal for money](http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/always-use-decimal-for-money) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to ask yourself what the data is.

If its words of fixed length its CHAR(n) ( such as a SKU number), VARCHAR(n) is variable length up to n, TEXT is for things longer such as a description.

If it's money, like a price, it's a float, double, or decimal in the database ( they are all essentially the same thing, depends on your DB ). If it's a whole number it's an integer. For an image, if it's the link ( the src ) then use a VarChar, but for image data itself its a BLOB.

```
Words "hello" = strings, varchar, char, text
Numbers "1" = integers 
floats   "1.01" = float, double, decimal etc.
binary data - such as images its called a BLOB or Binary Large Object
lists such as a status, "paid, due, late" you could use a ENUM type field.
```

Here is some reading meterial on types in MySql.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-overview.html

Comment: It's worth being aware of [an opposing view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2161328/472495), which suggests prices should be stored as integers, to avoid floating point rounding errors.

Comment: Never use floats to store money!